# Trying to add rules to search scope results in "Error: The search service is currently offline."

Tags: administration, search-scope

SharePoint 2007 Farm Environment. 1 Web Front End and 1 Index Server. Running version 12.0.0.6557.

The problem arises on any site collection not part of the main portal. For example if I go to site settings -> search scopes and try to add a rule I get:

> The search service is currently offline. Visit the Services on Server page in SharePoint Central Administration to verify whether the service is enabled. This might also be because an indexer move is in progress.

However, the search itself works fine. The server crawls fine daily. I can even add scopes and rules on the main intranet site but any additional site collection has this problem.

Here are some things I've tried that did NOT help:

- Stop/Start Search Service & Timer service
- psconfig force update on both servers
- add WSS_WSP account to tasks folder
- Patched to latest CU ... twice

So I'm out of ideas and now my customer is really in need of a more robust search solution that could be fixed with search scopes.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the web application that contains your site collection attached to the same Shared Service Provider as the other sites?

Comment: Yes, we have one SSP used by all the sites.